# jQuery live filter show message when filtered list is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script with live filter on page. How to show message when result is empty? For example uses my div.

My script:

```js
  $("#country_search").keyup(function () {
      var filter = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase();
       $('.country-box.search').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("h4").text().toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
            $(this).show();     
        } else {
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<div class="error"> No results </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It works for me**

```
  $("#country_search").keyup(function () {
        var filter = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase();
        $('.country-box.search').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("h4").text().toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
                $(this).show();  
                // result found, don't show error message   
                showError = false;
            } 
             else if($('.country-box.search:visible').length===0){
              $('.error').show();
          }
            else {
                 $(this).hide();
                 $('.error').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign variable (`showError` in my code) if any result was found.

```
// default value: show error message
var showError = true;
$("#country_search").keyup(function () {
    var filter = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase();
    $('.country-box.search').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("h4").text().toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
            $(this).show();  
            // result found, don't show error message   
            showError = false;
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});

if (showError) {
    $('.error').show();
}
```

Comment: Not works. I always see the error message

Comment: Is it right when I create `var showError = $( ".error" );`